# How to pass a module(account.js) name into main module(app.js) in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to inject the other module(account.js) into main module (app.js) in a SPA using angularJs as given below

```
var app = angular.module('UniversityApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'landing','account']);
```

angular.bootstrap(document, ['UniversityApp']); throws error "Uncaught Error: No module: myApp "

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['UniversityApp']);
```

instead

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)